# Where can I find puzzles on countable and uncountable sets?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, puzzle

I read some puzzles by Raymond Smullyan on countable and uncountable sets, are there other puzzles on that topic?

Comment: Find a set bigger than $\mathbb{N}$ but smaller than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I know a few puzzles but nothing close to a collection. It may help if you give some examples so we know what you mean by puzzle in this context.